# Why does the Facebook auth page say we "post on your behalf" even though we don't request publish_stream?

Tags: facebook

We have a mobile app (ios and android), and we request the following Facebook permissions when a user logs in to our app using Facebook:  "offline_access,user_birthday,user_relationships,email"

The Facebook Log In dialog has recently started to say that "This app may post on your behalf, including status updates, photos, and more."  We don't request the publish_stream permission, so does anyone know why this is appearing?  It's a rather scary sounding request that we'd rather not have show up.

If it matters, we're building an html5 app inside phonegap, using the facebook phonegap plugin to do log ins via the native Facebook app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug and was reported yesterday and is on dev facebook bugs.

Check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/273948536030203?browse=search_4f9067dad28a38e01247644)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I'll watch that bug and mark this as the answer if it solves our problem.

Answer (score 0):

Which permissions are you granted after login? That looks like the description for `publish_actions`, which is pretty similar in operation to `publish_stream` since some recent changes

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this blog of facebook: 
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/25/streamlining-publish_stream-and-publish_actions-permissions/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's harmless- their way of getting our permission to publish posts how you want them posted- for example, with the photos you are adding.